Why styles do not work properly with Material3 (Android)?
I am using the below code to add a style to RadioButtons in my app. The parent of the base theme of the app is Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar.
Below is the code:
<style name="RadioStyle">
    <item name="android:drawableStart">@drawable/mydrawable</item> 
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/anotherdrawable</item>
</style>

For some reason, the drawableStart is working fine, but the button is not being displayed. I can put them manually in each radiobutton, but I want to know why it is not working in style?
Also, when I was creating a style for a button, the backgroundTint attribute was working but the android:textColor was not. It was working fine with Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar, but not with Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar. I had to use the colorOnPrimary attribute instead. How to understand when which attribute is to be used in case of Material3 Library?

I tried to simulate the same and it worked perfectly. What I can understand from your code is you might have used android:theme attribute instead of style in the layout. If yes, then replace android:theme by style in the layout.
